# R building large data frame from file import

Tags: r, matlab, lambda

I have a large amount of data that I am importing from MATLAB .mat files, using the readMat command. The data has this characteristic layout: `struct$ERP: 200x256x16`, `struct$TGT: 200x1`, and some other extraneous stuff that I am discarding. The `TGT` variable is a classification target, and the third dimension is a trial index for each of the targets.

There are seven or more of these files in each separate subject folders--I would like to build an efficient structure that allows me to quickly work on individual trials (slices along the third dimension) while keeping track of the target variable, using correct R style.

I can do these steps in a relatively clumsy way with one subject's file:

```
require(R.matlab)
subdirs <- list.dirs(".")
filelist <- list.files(path = '.', full.names = FALSE, pattern = "^.*\\.mat$", 
                   ignore.case = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, 
                   include.dirs = FALSE)


sub1t1src <- as.data.frame(filedatas[1][1][[1]]$eeg)
erp1 <- sub1t1src[1,1]$ERP
erp1 <- aperm(erp1,c(2,3,1)) # data is permuted differently than I would like
erp1r <- apply(erp1,2,rbind)
erp1rdf <- as.data.frame(erp1r)

tgt1 <- sub1t1df[2,1]$TGT
tgt1 <- as.factor(tgt1)
tgt1r <- rep(tgt1,each=256)

sub1t1df <- cbind(erp1rdf,tgt1r)
```

This gets me a data frame that has each trial unfolded into rows, with the TGT variable repeated over each row. Is this a smart way to do this, or **is there a better way to organize the data that resembles the original MATLAB structure?**

**Most importantly, if this *is* a not-terrible way to do this, how can I iterate over each file in `filelist` and add something like the short subject name from `subdirs` to the data as a new column  the 'right' way with `apply` functions?**

Sample data (the .mats are binary so I'll just put a trimmed output from one subject):

```
subdirs <- c(".", "./s1", "./s2")
filelist <- c("s1/file1.dat.mat","s1/file2.dat.mat","s2/file1.dat.mat","s2/file2.dat.mat")
# for some reason subdirs are still in the output of filelist

sub1t1src <- structure(list(`1.1` = structure(list(ERP = structure(c(-10.5069999694824, 
-13.585000038147, -6.21299982070923, -11.6659994125366, -16.5679988861084, 
-17.1949996948242, -26.390998840332, -13.6799993515015, -0.759999990463257, 
-7.58099985122681, 23.5789985656738, -2.07099986076355, -7.3149995803833, 
-2.33699989318848, -18.1070003509521, -21.9639987945557), 
Csingle = TRUE, .Dim = c(2L, 
2L, 4L)), TGT = structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(4L, 1L)), FS = structure(256,
.Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = c("ERP", "TGT", "FS"))), 
.Names = "1.1", row.names = c("ERP", "TGT", "FS"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If your structure is `16x256x200` (and all numeric) you should put it into an array and not into a data.frame.

Comment: Looks not "not terrible" to me.

Comment: Most of the data is numeric, but each 16x256 'slice' is paired with one of the TGT classification factors.

Comment: You should add to your question what you want to do with the data in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account Roland's suggestion, here is, I guess, a bad way to do it with for loops. I separated the subjects because the object got too large.

```
subdirs <- list.dirs(".")

for (this_subd in 2:length(subdirs)) {
  erpdata <- array(dim = c(200,16,256)) # ERP array
  targets <- array(dim = c(200,1)) # Target array
  # look for all mat-files in that directory
  filelist <- list.files(path = subdirs[this_subd], full.names = FALSE, 
                         pattern = "^.*.mat$", 
                         ignore.case = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, 
                         include.dirs = FALSE)

  # combine current subdir path
  filelist <- paste(subdirs[this_subd],filelist,sep="/")

  # Anonymous function to work over each file and resave as R data
  filedatas <- lapply(filelist, function(x) {
    curdata <- readMat(con = x)
    return(curdata)
  })

  for (this_file in 2:length(filedatas)) {
    this_erp <- filedatas[][[this_file]]$eeg
    this_tgt <- this_erp[,,1]$TGT
    this_erp <- array(this_erp[,,1]$ERP,dim = c(200,16,256))
    erpdata <- abind(erpdata,this_erp,along=1)
    targets <- rbind(targets,this_tgt)
  }

  # Permute the data into  samples X channels X trials
  erpdata <- aperm(erpdata,c(3,2,1))
  # Remove NAs from originally initializing array
  erpdata <- array(erpdata[!is.na(erpdata)],dim = dim(erpdata))
  targets <- array(targets[!is.na(targets)],dim = dim(targets))
  targets <- as.factor(targets) # convert to categorical variable

  save(erpdata,targets,
       file = paste(subdirs[this_subd],"/",
                  substring(subdirs[this_subd],first=3),
                  "unifieddata.Rdata",
                  sep = "")
  )
  # cleanup to save memory
  rm(erpdata,targets,this_erp,this_tgt)
}
```